# Rename all the values within a column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataset, df, with the following values:

```
ID                                        Duration   
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz                1 sec
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1               0 sec
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz2               0 sec                    
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz3               1 sec
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz4               0 sec
```

Goal: I am plotting a histogram, and the values are just too lengthy. I would like to convert the values within the column ID to a shorter value such as:

```
ID                                        Duration   
A                                         1 sec
B                                         0 sec
C                                         0 sec                    
D                                         1 sec
E                                         0 sec
```

To do this, would I have to specify and write out every value within the row? (there are 100's of them)

```
rename.values(df, abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz="A")...
```

Comment: It can be done from the values itself `with(df, LETTERS[match(ID, unique(ID)])` or with `factor` `with(df, LETTERS[as.integer(factor(ID))])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without the use of `dplyr`, if you want to rename all values in your column ID to a shorter ID (and assuming that all of your IDs are different), you can write:

```r
df$ID <- paste0("A",1:nrow(df))
```

**Alternative: Using `gsub`**

Alternatively, if you have a very long pattern that you wish to replace (such abcdef....), you can use `gsub`:

```r
df$ID <- gsub("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz","A",df$ID)
```

The advantage with `gsub` is that if you have an ID repeted multiple times, it will conserve this repetition because it will replace only the first part of the ID string.

**Example**

```r
a <- paste0(letters[1:26], collapse = "")
df <- data.frame(ID = paste0(a,1:100),
                value = rnorm(100))
```

So, your `df` looks like:

```r
  ID      value
1 A1  2.6977546
2 A2  1.9434639
3 A3  0.4191808
4 A4 -0.1545246
5 A5  2.0112518
6 A6  0.5877203
...
```

Now, if you replace character strings of `ID` by the following command:

```r
df$ID <- paste0("A",1:100)
```

or with `gsub`:

```r
df$ID <- gsub("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz","A",df$ID)
```

And you get:

```r
  ID      value
1 A1  2.6977546
2 A2  1.9434639
3 A3  0.4191808
4 A4 -0.1545246
5 A5  2.0112518
6 A6  0.5877203
...
```

So, you conserved all of your columns and values in the same order and you just modify the ID column.

Comment: This worked! I will upvote this in 10 minutes. I want to add, I would like to actually retain the Duration column that is associated with the ID. How would I achieve this? Do I include the Duration column within the code? I am researching this

Comment: The command that I posted should not change the duration column because it is affected only to the column ID. Does the duration column disappear ?

Comment: let me look again please

Comment: new<-df$ID <- paste0("A",1:nrow(df))   When I did this, I now have a new row named V1 with all of my values renamed uniquely, however, I do not have the duration column included

Comment: because, you only attribute `df$ID` to your `new` object. What you have to do is: 1) `new <- df` and then `new$ID <- paste0("A",1:nrow(new))`. Then, you will conserve your `df` intact and modify only the column ID in `new`. Does it make sense ?

Comment: You're welcome. I edited my answer to provide you an alternative using `gsub` in case you have repeted IDs in your dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply create a new ID column, which would solve your issue and also preserve your original IDs (this assumes no duplicate IDs).

```
df <- df %>%
   mutate(ID2 = 1:nrow(df)) %>%
   select(ID2, Duration)        #  OR       select(-ID) : deselects ID, keeps everything else.
```

Comment: This works as well, I do not think I can 'check' two different answers. Thank you. This one works, it adds a new ID2 column to the already 2 existing columns. How do I just keep two columns? The one with the new renamed data, and the Duration?

Comment: Adding a select() statement should do the trick - I will make changes above.